# Jquery need to add additional selectors to a "toggled" function?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm pretty new to java/jquery and I'm trying to create a script for a nice horizontal slide nav menu.  The basic slide function works fine (via some nice code by mplungjan), but I want to add an additional selector element to make the nav menu slide back in.

Here's the current code:

```
$(function() {                      
  $('.icon').on("click",function(e) {
      if ($(this).data("show")=="no") {
        $('.nav').css({left:'0'});
        $(this).data("show","yes");
      }   
      else {
        $('.nav').css({left:'16%'});
        $(this).data("show","no");     
      }
  });
});
```

Currently, the .icon element triggers the slide open and closed.

MY QUESTION:  How do I add an additional element to make the menu slide close, but have it only work when it is open?  ie you can click the .icon to open it and then click another div to have it close - but that this div only works when the nav menu is open.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JNGVB/

- again, this part works fine.  I'd just like to add the ability to close the menu by clicking anywhere else, conditional on the menu being open.

Comment: Post your HTML please. You should probably just add a toggle for your menu

Comment: You don't really need to set a variable to store the visibility status. As you're using jQuery, you can easily find out whether something is visible. From this point, you can just use a toggle.

Comment: jQuery has [Sliding](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/sliding/) built in, could you use that? then on the other element you would just call `slideUp()` and it would only slide up if it was open

Comment: Slide functions aren't suitable - I'm sliding horizontally, not up or down

Comment: @MelanciaUK the toggle function was deprecated in v1.9... hence needing to find different, more complicated solutions

Comment: Could you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you have now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Your fiddle, updated.](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/JNGVB/2/)**

HTML: Change the starting `data-show` to `yes`:

```
<div class="nav" data-show="yes">
```

JavaScript: Add another class to the selector (`'.icon,.other'`), to get the `data` attribute, use `$('.nav')` instead of `$(this)`, and place an `if` to only trigger closing when `.icon`:

```
$('.icon,.other').on("click", function (e) {
    if ($('.nav').data("show") == "no") {
        // close event
        $('.nav').css({ left: '0' });
        $('.nav').data("show", "yes");
    } else {
        // open event
        if ($(this).is('.other')) { // dont open when .other
            return;
        }
        $('.nav').css({ left: '16%' });
        $('.nav').data("show", "no");
    }
});
```

**Explanation:** As you want to make another element (in my example, an element with a class `other`) only close the menu, you should just add it to the click event (thus the `'.icon,.other'` part), but only call the opening part if the clicked element is not the one with `.other` (thus the `if` with the checking `$(this).is('.other')`).

Comment: Yes!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I'm sure you're right, there probably are a lot of issues with it - this is only my second day messing with jquery...

Comment: I meant I had to change more than one thing to get it quite like you wanted. But, hey, second day? You're doing good. It took me quite some time to really get the grasp of it. :)

Comment: Yea it worked well.  I'm using the #frame div as the second element so you can just click anywhere to close the menu.  Next challenge... figuring out how to link this with media queries *_*

Answer (score 0):

if you use [slide](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/sliding/) you can accomplish it like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.icon').on('click',$('.nav').slideToggle);
    $('.otherSelector').on('click',$('.nav').slideUp);
});
```

The element will only slide up if it is currently showing. Otherwise with your current code you can check the css left property and close it when it is set to 16%

```
$('.otherSelector').on('click',function(){
    var $nav = $('.nav');
    if($nav.css('left') == '16%'){
        $.nav.css('left','0');
        $('.icon').data('show','yes');
});
```